# How can I invert the case of a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, case, case-sensitive

I want to change a String so that all the uppercase characters become lowercase, and all the lower case characters become uppercase. Number characters are just ignored.

so "AbCdE123" becomes "aBcDe123"

I guess there must be a way to iterate through the String and flip each character, or perhaps some regular expression that could do it.

Comment: No, regex cannot be used in this case.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything built-in to do this (it's relatively unusual). This should do it though:

```
public static String reverseCase(String text)
{
    char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    {
        char c = chars[i];
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
        {
            chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        }
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(c))
        {
            chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Note that this doesn't do the locale-specific changing that String.toUpperCase/String.toLowerCase does. It also doesn't handle non-BMP characters.

Comment: This is almost precisely what the Apache Commons StringUtils code does, actually, except that they use charAt() to get each Character instead of converting to and from an array.  Also, they check isTitleCase() as well (and convert to lower).

Comment: @JacobM: How do they build the array in the end? I find that going to a char array, modifying in place and then building a String at the end is one of the more efficient ways of doing this sort of work.

Comment: Looks like they start by allocating a StringBuffer and appending each converted character to the buffer.  I guess then the question is whether StringBuffer.toString is more or less efficient than new String(char[]).  I couldn't tell you.  Source code available at http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java.htm

Comment: By using StringBuffer rather than StringBuilder they're already incurring the (small) synchronization penalty on every operation. Then there's the internal housekeeping for StringBuffer, keeping the length vs capacity etc. I'm not saying it's a big difference - but in both cases there'll be an extra (unavoidable) extra copy made, and I can't see any actual advantages to the StringBuffer approach.

Comment: @Sam: It may well depend on the version of Java you're using, but in the source code I'm looking at right now (1.6 I believe), StringBuffer.toString() uses the `public String(char[], int, int)` constructor which copies the array. (Any public constructor will have to copy the array, of course.)

Comment: This is quickly devolving into pedantry, at any rate it used to be the case that calling StringBuffer.toString() would reuse the char[] array by calling a package-private String constructor.  I just checked, and that's no longer the case in 1.5+, StringBuilder and StringBuffer's toString methods copy the char array.  At any rate, I like the char[] approach better.

Comment: Sam: String(Buffer|Builder).toString must have created a copy in earlier Java versions as well, as modifications to the StringBuffer cannot cause changes to previosuly created String instances.

Comment: @jambjo: In 1.4, StringBuffer.toString() called new String(this) which referenced the original char[] array, and called setShared(true) on the StringBuffer.  Any further modification to the "shared" StringBuffer caused the StringBuffer's char[] array to be copied, and unset the "shared" flag.  This is no longer the case in 1.5+, maybe because it's more important to append things quickly to StringBuffers and StringBuilders without checking whether they're shared for every write operation.

Answer (score 25):

Apache Commons StringUtils has a [swapCase](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#swapCase-java.lang.String-) method.

Comment: Their StringUtils is one of the best tools for manipulating strings.

Comment: Adding a dependency to a largish library for only a single function of very limited complexity could be argued against.

Comment: Agreed about the dependency, but if you look around you'll probably find other places that Commons code can simplify your code.

Comment: I'd also add that there are advantages to using an approach that is known to be heavily tested and widely used, such as Apache Commons.  If you implemented it yourself, there might be nothing wrong with your basic algorithm, but (unless you get Jon Skeet to write it for you) you might have a little off-by-one error or some such that won't turn up until later.

Answer (score 4):

**Java 8 and above:**

```
String myString = "MySampleString123";
System.out.println(myString.chars().map(c -> Character.isLetter(c) ? c ^ ' ' : c).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString());
```

Code which is inverting the case of letter, is important to notice:

```
Character.isLetter(c) ? c ^ ' ' : c
```

Comment: I've just used the calculator to verify (`XOR`ing with space) based on the ascii table indices, it seems to work but i never heard of this before so could you explain why this works ? Was the ASCII table designed with this in mind from the start ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52650157/3225638 
This answer states that it was a deliberate decision, that's a damn nice trick though

Comment: @Lorenzo it's been designed deliberately, switching case of a letter by set/unset a bit at 6th place

Answer (score 2):

> *I guess there must be a way to iterate through the String and flip each character*

Correct. The [`java.lang.Character`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class provides you under each the `isUpperCase()` method for that. Test on it and make use of the `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` methods depending on the outcome. Append the outcome of each to a `StringBuilder` and you should be fine.

Comment: No need to append to a StringBuilder - you already know exactly how big the output will be, and you can do it in an array in-place.

Comment: That's indeed doable if he don't need to manipulate it afterwards.

Comment: Jon: If you honour locale-specific rules, changing the case of a string does not necessarily keep the length. E.g. the upper case of "ß" is "SS" for German locales.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Faraz's approach, I think the character conversion can be as simple as:

```
t += Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toLowerCase(c) : Character.toUpperCase(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the  simplest solution to understand would be something like:

```java
public static String reverseCase(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : text.toCharArray())
        sb.append(Character.isUpperCase(c) ? 
                Character.toLowerCase(c) : 
                Character.toUpperCase(c));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I think you can read through this easier and StringBuilder has an append(char) method anyways + `Character.toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` are both just static methods. I just felt bad that the only StringBuilder example had ascii index arithmetics included as well.

For those who don't like ternary expressions, here's the equivalent:

```java
public static String reverseCase(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : text.toCharArray())
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) 
            c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        else
            c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
        sb.append(c);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

EDIT Java 8+ (StringBuilder collector code taken from @Arun's answer)

```java
public static String reverseCase(String text) {
    return text.chars()
        .map(c -> Character.isUpperCase(c) ? 
            Character.toLowerCase(c) : 
            Character.toUpperCase(c))
        .collect(
            StringBuilder::new,
            StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
            StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Comment: why not ? sb.append(Character.isUpperCase(c) ? 
                Character.toLowerCase(c) : 
                Character.isUpperCase(c));

Comment: Hmm I think you mean `Character.toUpperCase` for the if `false` condition, but I guess you're right, let me clean this up

Answer (score 0):

We can also use a StringBuilder object, as it has character replacing methods. However, it might take some extra space to store the StringBuilder object. So, it will help if space does not matter and keep the solution simple to understand.

```
String swapCase(String text) {
    StringBuilder textSB = new StringBuilder(text);
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if(text.charAt(i) > 64 && text.charAt(i) < 91)
            textSB.setCharAt(i, (char)(text.charAt(i) + 32));
        else if(text.charAt(i) > 96 && text.charAt(i) < 123)
            textSB.setCharAt(i, (char)(text.charAt(i) - 32));
    }
    return textSB.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReverseCase {
    public  static void main(String[] args){ 
        char[] char_arr = args[0].toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < char_arr.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(char_arr[i])) {
                char_arr[i] = Character.toUpperCase(char_arr[i]);
            }else {
                char_arr[i] = Character.toLowerCase(char_arr[i]);
            }
        }
        String reversed = new String(char_arr);
        System.out.println(reversed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I do realize that the given thread is very old, but there is a better way of solving it:

```
class Toggle
{ 
    public static void main()
    { 
        String str = "This is a String";
        String t = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < str.length(); x++)
        {  
            char c = str.charAt(x);
            boolean check = Character.isUpperCase(c);
            if (check == true)
                t = t + Character.toLowerCase(c);
            else
                t = t + Character.toUpperCase(c);
        }
        System.out.println (t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you care to explain why this is "better"? It's (*functionally*) not (very) different than [the already accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1729815/215042). You do, however, not use a fixed length array or stringbuilder so your solution is, in that sense, even worse 'cause of much more (re)allocations required. Another thing is that you're introducing a variable `check` which is, at least, not very descriptive. Also; it's a matter of style/taste but if it were up to me I'd just write `if (Character.isUpperCase(c))` instead of first assigning `check` and then checking the variable…