# Xoring alphabet letters with space character

Tags: unicode, ascii, xor

Is there a historical reason as to why Xoring any alphabetic letter with the space character changes the case of the letter? (i.e., 'a' xor ' ' = 'A', 'F' xor ' ' = 'f', etc...)

Or is this just a coincidence?

(Assuming the characters are ASCII- or unicode-encoded.)

Comment: It also happens to work in EBCDIC.

Answer (score 17):

I'm sure it was deliberate that the case could be changed by changing a single bit - it will have made early software much more efficient. The fact that the space character is #32 is irrelevant.

Answer (score 10):

From the wikipedia entry on ASCII:

> The code itself was patterned so that most control codes were
>   together, and all graphic codes were together, for ease of
>   identification. The first two columns (32 positions) were reserved for
>   control characters.[19] The "space" character had to come before
>   graphics to make sorting easier, so it became position 20hex;[20] for
>   the same reason, many special signs commonly used as separators were
>   placed before digits. The committee decided it was important to
>   support upper case 64-character alphabets, and chose to pattern ASCII
>   so it could be reduced easily to a usable 64-character set of graphic
>   codes.[21] Lower case letters were therefore not interleaved with
>   upper case. To keep options available for lower case letters and other
>   graphics, the special and numeric codes were arranged before the
>   letters, and the letter "A" was placed in position 41hex to match the
>   draft of the corresponding British standard.[22] The digits 0–9 were
>   arranged so they correspond to values in binary prefixed with 011,
>   making conversion with binary-coded decimal straightforward.

So it seems that the behaviour is a happy coincidence.

Answer (score 4):

#### Good Point

ASCII is a child of the codes used by electromechanical teletypewriters commonly known by the brand name Teletype.

These machines had no active electronics ... they used drums, motors, and cams and about a zillion metal parts to print upper-case characters.  They had a few RLC components and various relays.

It was quite deliberate that only a single bit separates the upper and lower case characters. This way transmission and storage systems could use 6 bits instead of 7.

In fact, you don't need XOR, you can use OR or ADD to get the lower case range.

By simply ignoring the one bit, a device that could only print upper case was able to handle mixed-case input. It kind of makes sense that this bit would be used in a space character ... it's a bit that was typically ignored in terms of type element selection.

[Here is a quite old one restored to working order.](http://www.aetherltd.com/refurbishing15.html)

Comment: On a lot of uppercase-only equipment, the shift key would unconditionally toggle bit 4, thus turning "1" into "!", "/" into "?", "P" into "@", and incidentally "Q" into "A".  On equipment with upper-lower case, the shift key would toggle bit 4 of values where bit 6 was clear, and bit 5 if bit 6 was set.  Much easier than using a per-key lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a feature of ASCII letters and some other sets of letters allocated in a similar manner. For the vast majority of alphabetic characters in Unicode, it just doesn’t happen. E.g., Ā is U+0100, ā is U+0101. In general, lower and upper case letter have commonly been allocated to consecutive code positions. And most alphabetic characters in Unicode have no lowercase/uppercase concept.

Answer (score 1):

In ASCII, the uppercase letters are sequential binary numbers starting with A = 1**0**0.0001, while  the lowercase letters are sequential binary numbers starting with a = 1**1**0.0001. In other words, a letter's case can be changed by flipping the second bit. Flipping the second bit is equivalent to a bitwise XOR with 010.0000. That happens to be the ASCII representation of the space character.

As others have noted, it was certainly deliberate that uppercase and lowercase letters differ by just one bit. From this it follows that XORing any letter with the character represented by a 1 in that bit and a 0 in every other bit will flip its case. But it seems unlikely that this is the *reason* the space character was assigned to 010.0000. If it had made more sense for 010.0000 to be a period, or a dollar sign, or the digit 0, or any other character, it would still be just as easy to flip the case of a letter with XOR, using whatever that character was.

(Note that I'm just using the periods inside the binary numbers to group the bits in order to make them easier to read. They aren't of any other significance.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not coincidence, It is always true.

```
   Example:  hex of 'a' = 61  hex of space = 20 XOR 'a' and space = 41 = 'A' (in hex)
   same as:  hex of 'z' = 7A  hex of space = 20 XOR 'z' and space = 5A = 'Z' (in hex)
```