# java controle upper and lowercase in 2 String

Tags: java, uppercase, lowercase

I want to check if every character in a string is the inverse of the other character in the second. By inverse I mean uppercase and lowercase.

For example these strings:

1. `Ahh7h`
2. `aHH7H`

The result will be `true`

I wrote this code but the result is always `false`.  Why?

```
public boolean checkString(String serverString, String clientString) {
    if (serverString.length() != clientString.length())
        return false;
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < clientString.length(); i++) {
            if ((clientString.charAt(i) >= '0' && clientString.charAt(i) <= '9')
                    && (clientString.charAt(i) != serverString.charAt(i)))
                return false;
            else if (clientString.charAt(i) >= 'A'
                    && clientString.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
                if ((int) clientString.charAt(i) != ((int) serverString
                        .charAt(i) + 32))
                    return false;
            } else if (clientString.charAt(i) >= 'a'
                    && clientString.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
                if ((int) clientString.charAt(i) != ((int) serverString
                        .charAt(i) - 32))
                    return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!  Also note there is never a need for more then one blank line of white space.

Answer (score 0):

You could "invert" one string using: [How can I invert the case of a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729778/how-can-i-invert-the-case-of-a-string-in-java) and then use Strings .equals method to compare them.

Method from [How can I invert the case of a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729778/how-can-i-invert-the-case-of-a-string-in-java) included for completeness:

```
public static String reverseCase(String text)
{
    char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    {
        char c = chars[i];
        if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
        {
            chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        }
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(c))
        {
            chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've switched the `+ 32` and the `- 32`.

By the way, it's a lot easier to use methods like:

```
Character.isDigit
Character.isLowerCase
Character.isUpperCase
Character.toLowerCase
Character.toUpperCase
```