# How to Toggle/Switch the Case of every letter in a text file?

Tags: java, switch-statement, toggle, uppercase, lowercase

Ok so here is the code I created for the program to read a text file.
Now can someone tell me how to switch every letter's case from uppercase to lower and vice versa in the result? Notice that I want the program to read the file from the command line and not a string.
If possible I'd like the answer in code :| Thanks
I am very new in Java and could use some help thanks.

```
public class Main {

        /**
        * @param args the command line arguments
        */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
         java.io.File file = new           java.io.File("C:\\Users\\Lifeless\\Desktop\\123.txt");

        try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
        String num = input.nextLine();  //grabs line
        System.out.println(num);
        }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.format("File does not exist \n");
```

Comment: This is a duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729778/how-can-i-invert-the-case-of-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I used a bufferedReader and put all lines of the file in an ArrayList.

```
static ArrayList<String> lines;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
  {
    lines = new ArrayList<>();
    File f = new File(args[0]);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

    String line = r.readLine ();
    while(line != null)
    {
      lines.add(invert(line));
      line = r.readLine ();
    }
    for(String  s : lines)
    {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }

  private static String invert(String line)
  {
    char[] singleChars = line.toCharArray (); //split Line into single Characters
    for(int i = 0;i< singleChars.length;i++) //Iterate over every single Character
    {
      if(Character.isAlphabetic (singleChars[i]))
      {
        if(Character.isUpperCase (singleChars[i])) //swap Upper to Lower and vice versa
        {
          singleChars[i] = Character.toLowerCase (singleChars[i]);
        }else
        {
          singleChars[i] = Character.toUpperCase (singleChars[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return new String(singleChars);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...can you tell me how and where to add my command line from which it will read the file?

Comment: you can easily copy&paste my class. it reads the file from the arguments you pass to the class when executing it.
`File f = new File(args[0]);` takes the file name. The file itself is located in the same directory as your class file, if you write your file only and not a path

Comment: no. When executing your class in the command prompt e.g. `java Test`, you pass an argument of your filename eg. `java Test D:/Path/To/Your/File.txt` you can also write `java Test File.txt` then the file is in the same folder like your Class

Comment: firstly i am sorry for the very late reply.as my internet was down..i couldnt
Next i want to ask should it be like this File f =Testfile.txt C:/Path/to/my/testfile.txt' 
like this? or does Java test remain the same?

Comment: Also, while pasting this code i get 2 errors which i do not know how to solve one is here 'lines = new ArrayList<>();' here it says "diamond operator is not supported in source -1.6, (Use source 7 or higher to use the diamond operator) 
Next comes here 'if(Character.isAlphabetic (singleChars[i]))' here it says "cannot find symbol 
symbol: Method is isAlphabetic(char)
location: class character"

Kindly tell me how to remove these

Comment: first: Use Java 7 or Java 8, this allows using generics (using <> operator)
you can also remove `if(Character.isAlphabetic (singleChars[i]))`

Comment: Ok what about the Command line e.e
sorry for not understanding..but i dont have a teacher and i am trying to learn this by internet :|