# Convert java char inside string to lowerCase/upperCase

Tags: java, string, character, uppercase, lowercase

I have a String called "originalstring" which contains a sentence with mixed upper and lower case characters.

I simply want to flip the string so that if a character is a lowercase make it upper case and vice versa and return it.

I have tried this code, which returns the original string in upperCase:

```
for (int i = 0; i < originalString.length(); i++) {
        char c = originalString.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            originalString += Character.toLowerCase(c);

        }

        if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            originalString += Character.toUpperCase(c);

        }

    }
    return originalString;
```

Comment: `+=` to convert?? That's odd

Comment: Is this your actual code? Looks like an infinite loop to me at a glance...

Comment: How could this possibly be an infinite loop? You need an else statement. Your first `if` converts uppercase letters to lower case letters. It then imminently goes into your second `if` statement, and converts it to an upper case. Just switch the second `if` to an `else`. Id also recommend using a StringBuilder.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729778/how-can-i-invert-the-case-of-a-string-in-java

Comment: @user489041 because it adds to `originalString` without removing characters, and `originalString.length()` is in the loop termination condition. Of course it would eventually run out of memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding characters to the original string.  Also, this means that your `for` loop will never get to the end of the iteration of the `for` loop, because `originalString.length()` changes each loop also.  It's an infinite loop.

Instead, create a `StringBuilder` that stores the converted characters as you're iterating over the original string.  The convert it to a `String` and return it at the end.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(originalString.length());
for (int i = 0; i < originalString.length(); i++) {
    char c = originalString.charAt(i);

    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        buf.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));

    }
    else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
        buf.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));

    }
    // Account for case: neither upper nor lower
    else {
        buf.append(c);
    }

}
return buf.toString();
```

Answer (score 6):

Common-lang provide a `swapCase` function, see [the doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#swapCase(java.lang.String)). Sample from the doc:

```
StringUtils.swapCase(null)                 = null
StringUtils.swapCase("")                   = ""
StringUtils.swapCase("The dog has a BONE") = "tHE DOG HAS A bone"
```

And if you really want to do it by yourself, you can check the source of [common-lang `StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.5803)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using existing utilities, you may try below conversion using boolean operation:

To upper case:

```
 char upperChar = (char) (c & 0x5f)
```

To lower case:

```
   char lowerChar = (char) (c ^ 0x20)
```

In your program:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(originalString.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < originalString.length(); i++) {
            char c = originalString.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                result.append((char) (c ^ 0x20));

            }
            else if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) {
                result.append((char) (c & 0x5f));

            }
            else {
                result.append(c);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(result);
```