# Cannot return modified String from static method

Tags: java, string, return

Im very new to coding and cant seem to be able to return anything. I need to convert upper case characters to lower case and vice versa. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    invString(str);
    sc.close();

}

private static String invString(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch > 97) {
            ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
            return str;
        } else {
            ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
            return str;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

What am i doing wrong? ( in terms of returning, the code isnt complete yet)

EDIT****************

thanks for the helpful remarks, as i understood i do not have a place where my modifications are stored, so i added  `String res = "";` and kept adding the values into `String res` but in the end, when returning res, i still dont get any output...Here is the whole thing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    String st = invString(str);
    sc.close();

}

private static String invString(String str) {
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (65 <= ch && ch <= 90) {
            ch += 32;
            res += ch;

        } else if (97 <= ch && ch <= 122) {
            ch -= 32;
            res += ch;
        }


    }

    return res;
}
```

ps. Im not using the ready methods because my task asks for it.

Comment: What is the problem? There is a logical error, since either the `if`-  or the `else`-block is entered, therefore the loop is executed exactly once iff. `str.length() > 0`. You are using the `return` Statement (syntactically) correct.

Comment: "Can't seem to"? Be *specific*. Most likely, you're making multiple erroneous assumptions about how variables and strings work in Java--strings are immutable, and assigning values to variables doesn't change other objects that have their own variables.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1729815/3885376

Comment: There is no reason you downvote everyones answer ,

Comment: @PranoySarkar Because 2/5 is "everyone" (yes, I did downvote and I retracted my downvotes after the posters responded to my complains).

Comment: You return immediately after the first character. Also you return the original String without doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of flaws in your code. Firstly, you are attempting to return the original string `str` in every `if` statement. So what happens is the method `invString( String )` simply returns the original string that is passed as argument. Instead, you should keep adding the characters to a new String variable (as [@Massimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6898301/massimo) said). Also, you are returning `null` in the end. Why even do that? You would want to return the new String variable instead.

```
private static String invString(String str) {

    String s=""; //new String variable
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch > 97) {
            ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
            s+=ch; //do this instead of returning str
        } else {
            ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
            s+=ch; //same here
        }
    }
    return s; //return the new String
}
```

Secondly, in your main method, simply calling the method is wrong as it returns a value. You should assign the value returned by `invString()` to a String variable.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
    String st = invString(str); //st stores the value of str with 
                                //letters' cases changed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You return you str object without updating it at all.
You should generate a new string in which put the characters for which you reverse the case.
Check the last answers in 
[How can I invert the case of a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729778/how-can-i-invert-the-case-of-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the inverted string, you need to actually use the returned value, e.g:

```
str = invString (str)
```

Strings are immutable so you can't change the characters within them. You can only replace the string variable with a new string.

Modifying the characters you are accessing doesn't affect the string. You need to build a new string (look up [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)) and return it.

Comment: "You need to actually use the returned value" - this is not true. You can call a method with an return type other than void and not assign its returned value to some variable.

Comment: I didn't mean it that way! I just meant you need to use the returned value if you want to access the new value and not throw away the result.

Comment: Then you should write it that way.

Comment: I have added a qualifier that should satisfy pedants