# How to reverse the case of a string in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

What's the most efficient way to reverse the case of a string?

```
input = "Hello World"
output = "hELLO wORLD"
```

Here upper case character will be converted to lower case and vice versa.

**Is there any default library support to do this?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729778/how-can-i-invert-the-case-of-a-string-in-java The answer for Kotlin is still "not in the standard library", but  most of these answers can be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String extension function to reverse the case of a string:

**Way 1: Using CharArray**

```
fun String.reverseCaseOfString(): String {
    val inputCharArr = toCharArray() // Converting the input to char array
    var output = ""
    for (i in 0 until inputCharArr.size) {
        output += if (inputCharArr[i].isUpperCase()) { // Checking the character is in uppercase or not
            inputCharArr[i].toLowerCase() // Converting the char to lower case
        } else {
            inputCharArr[i].toUpperCase() // Converting the char to upper case
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

**Way 2: Using CharIterator**

```
private fun String.reverseCaseOfString(): String {
    val charIterator = iterator() // CharIterator of string
    var output = ""
    for (char in charIterator) {
        output += if (char.isUpperCase()) { // Checking the character is in uppercase or not
            char.toLowerCase() // Converting the char to lower case
        } else {
            char.toUpperCase() // Converting the char to upper case
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

Then you can use this extension function by the below code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Hello World".reverseCaseOfString())
}
```

Output: `hELLO wORLD`

Default library support is not available till now to reverse the case of a string.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin I would propose something like this:

```
fun String.reverseCase(): String = map { if (it.isUpperCase()) it.toLowerCase() else it.toUpperCase() }.joinToString("")
```

Convert every Char in the String to its opposite and then join to String with no delimiter.

Which can be used as follows:

```
val input = "Hello WorLD"
val expected = "hELLO wORld"
input.reverseCase() shouldBeEqualTo expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at this, with the goal of keeping the code easy to read but also performant.

```
fun String.invertCase(): String {
    val array = this.toCharArray()
    this.forEachIndexed { index, char ->
        when {
            char.isUpperCase() -> array[index] = char.toLowerCase()
            char.isLowerCase() -> array[index] = char.toUpperCase()
        }
    }
    return String(array)
}

val input = "Hello World"
println(input.invertCase()) // hELLO wORLD
```

Answer (score -1):

For me an elegant way is:

1. to create an extension function for Char:

   `fun Char.reverseCase(): Char = if (isUpperCase()) toLowerCase() else toUpperCase()`
2. and then use it to create the extension for String:

   `fun String.reverseCase(): String = toCharArray().map { it.reverseCase() }.joinToString("")`