# How to invert the case of a single character?

Tags: java

```
package nine.march.twenty;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpperCaseToLowerCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char ch='a';
        
    }
}
```

If I put 'a' I want 'A '

If I put 'A' I want 'a'

Comment: Well, basically you need to invert the case. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729778/how-can-i-invert-the-case-of-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Character.isUpperCase()` to determine what case the character is, and `Character.toLowerCase()` and `Character.toUpperCase()` to change the case.

```
char c = 'A';
char result = Character.isUpperCase(c) ? Character.toLowerCase(c) : Character.toUpperCase(c);
System.out.println(result);
```

Which prints:

```
a
```

Comment: If you need it to be locale-sensitive, it is recommend that one use `String#toUpperCase`.